# Multiple boxes same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have a content in 3 different boxes as defined in some classes (e.g. box-cls). The style is for all the three the same. Therefore I get in an example:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| 12 34   | my long | ab de   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

When I shrink the page than the content of the boxes is also reduced. I would have expected to see it like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| 12 34 | my    | ab de |
|       | long  |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Matter of fact I see the boxes in the class shrink like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| 12 34 | my    | ab de |
+-------+ long  +-------+
        +-------+
```

1. Is there a way to adjust the box height dynamically to the max height of a box?
2. If 1) is not possible: Is it possible to set the height fixed as soon as the the length of the boxes falls below a fixed limit?

I tried with some `@media`but didn't succeed in the proper styling.
Currently I have only a fixed solution:

```
.box-content {
    min-height: 46px!important;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 }
```

but would like to have a more dynamic solution - cuz with my approach the height is in many cases to large!
Looking for a CSS-solution - not a JQuery (or similar)

Comment: Can you please add code of your boxes? Preferably in code snippet. Because flex-container should automatically adjust box height by default (`align-items: justify`).

Comment: 1. Yes... Use `align-items: stretch;`

Comment: @Vadim: Sorry, I do NOT understand what I should add. If I do not set the min-height of the element I get the different results. And the `justify` doesn't help. Or you mean something like `<div class...>12 34</div>`???

Comment: @Jozi: If I try: `.box-content{display: flex; align-items: stretch;}` this does not help either :-/ Or how do you expect the complete style should look like? Remark: `align-items: center` aligns the item in the middle of the box (perhaps not really good displayed in my two-line ASCII-sample :-/)

Comment: @LeO I'm asking you to provide code to reproduce your issue and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.boxes{
  display: flex;                  /* 1. */
}

.box {
  flex: 1;                        /* 2. */
  border: 1px solid chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">12 34</div>
  <div class="box"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam voluptate, optio magni hic et non voluptatibus ipsum voluptates, quisquam suscipit consectetur ea eveniet ut eos corporis perspiciatis error temporibus aut.
  </div>
  <div class="box">ab de</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `flex`, you can use `table/table-cell` which has better browser support.

```css
.wrap {
  display: table;
}
.box-content {
    min-height: 46px!important;
    display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box-content">12 34</div>
  <div class="box-content">my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long my long </div>
  <div class="box-content">ab de</div>
</div>
```